# How to Implement Android Interface in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

How to implement android interface in xamarin where there is no delegate alternative. Like this `ListPopupWindow.SetOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.IOnItemClickListener clickListener)` ?

Answer (score 5):

There is god document on xamarin official site which addresses this topic [Android Callable Wrappers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/android_callable_wrappers/)
The main thing to remember is to subclass `Java.Lang.Object`.

I also made my own wrapper so that I can reuse it in my code using delegates.

```
public class OnItemClickListener : Object, AdapterView.IOnItemClickListener{
        public delegate void ItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id);

        public OnItemClickListener(ItemClick itemClickDelegate){
            ItemClickDelegate = itemClickDelegate;
        }

        public ItemClick ItemClickDelegate { get; }

        public void OnItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id){
            ItemClickDelegate(parent, view, position, id);
        }
    }
```

And usage:

```
new CallbackWrapers.OnItemClickListener(
                delegate (AdapterView parent, View view1, int position, long id) { 
                     //Do your stuff
                }));
```